# Install Openfire when port 9090 is already in use?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openfire

I tried to install Openfire on Ubuntu 16.04 it installed fine but when I go to: http://localhost:9090 it shows me "prometheus" graph page

I wanted to know if I could install openfire or configure openfire to use a different port instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try finding a file with name openfire.xml. The location of the file differs according to the way of installation. Use the following command for finding it

```
sudo find / -name openfire.xml
```

Inside that file there will be a line `<port>9090</port>` just replace 9090 with the required port no and then restart the application.